# openpyxl does not support .xml file format, please check you can open it with Excel first. Supported formats are: .xlsx,.xlsm,.xltx,.xltm

Tags: python

I am reading a file `hello.txt` using open function of file handling.

```
with open("hello.txt", 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
```

This is working as expected

But when I import openpyxl the I got the following error

```
from openpyxl import *

with open("hello.txt", 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
```

The following error occured

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\hello.py", line 2, in <module>
       with open("hello.txt", 'r') as file:
   File "C:\app\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
       reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
   File "C:\app\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", 
line 124, in __init__
       self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
   File "C:\app\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", 
line 94, in _validate_archive
       raise InvalidFileException(msg)
openpyxl.utils.exceptions.InvalidFileException: openpyxl does not support .txt file format, please check you can open it with Excel first. Supported formats are: .xlsx,.xlsm,.xltx,.xltm
```

This open function is redirecting to

```
def load_workbook(filename, read_only=False, keep_vba=KEEP_VBA,
              data_only=False, keep_links=True):`
```

It is not expected to execute when importing openpyxl